# How to align title of google map marker to right for RTL in ios?

Tags: ios8, nsstring, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using code below to set title in marker for google maps.

```
  CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, longi);
    GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
    marker.title = self.TitleArray[i];
    marker.map = mapView_;
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to align title to right ?

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
   marker.title.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
```